# NullPointerException when trying to autowire configuration properties running with MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I have been trying to use configuration properties in my test classes but couldn't find the way to do so as I always get NullPointerException.

application.yaml

```
affix:
  lover: 'interests'
  social: 'social_media'
```

YamlConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Data
public class YamlConfig {
    private HashMap<String, String> affix;
}
```

Service.java

```
@Autowired
private YamlConfig config;

...

setFeatureName(config.getAffix().get("social"));
// supposed to return social_media
```

The code above is working fine in my service but when I tried to use configuration properties in my test classes, it didn't work.

ServiceTest.java

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MetadataServiceTest {
@Autowired
private YamlConfig config;

@Test
public void testPropertiesNotNull() {
  assertNotNull(config.getAffix().get("social"));
}
```

I've also tried other annotations as well, but none of them seemed to work. Most of the example are running test using JUnitRunner, and I'm not sure if that's the reason why they didn't work on my test classes.

Is there anyway to get configuration properties to use in test class using MockitoJUnitRunner without mocking the whole thing (the actual config is very large and would be hard to mock result for each one)?

Comment: You don't start your tests in the spring context, and thus `@Autowired` is not picked up, so nothing is injected. Either use mocks or spring, don't mix them both. (I suggest mocks)

Answer (score 0):

Your `@Autowired` in test is ignored, as you don't have any Spring context selected. Make it an integration Spring test with annotation.

Comment: Can you please provice me the exact annotation, I'm just lost.

Comment: @clumsy.kitten
`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = YamlConfig.class)`
Something like this, but keep in mind that it has its consequences. Read about integration tests in Spring
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using @Autowired annotation, you should use for ex: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

In that way you will start your tests in spring context.

But if you still want to use MockitoJUnitRunner, instead of using @Autowired you can use:
@InjectMocks
private YamlConfig config;